# Как из byte[] получить Bitmap?

Tags: java, android

Я делаю предварительный просмотр фото. Вызываю функцию

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
```

и она возвращает массив `byte[] data` как мне его конвертировать в `Bitmap`, чтоб сохранять изображения с камеры в `ArrayList<Bitmap>`?

Хочу таким способом из `ArrayList` предварительно показывать пользователю снимки которые он сделал. Если все отснятые снимки подходят, то будет возможность сохранить все фото из массива в память телефона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int))

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

`decodeByteArray` вернёт декодированный `Bitmap`. Если не сможет декодировать, то вернёт `null`

Comment: Когда я добавляю эту строчку то вылетает приложение при чем показывает, что вылетает в onResume... вообще не пойму...  вот ссылка на проект https://github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/CameraAndroid.git  помогите пожалуйста разобраться...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, локализуйте проблему и добавьте проблемный код  с текстом ошибки в тело вопроса.

Comment: Только что все получилось... Нашел решение здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758560/android-bitmap-to-byte-array-and-back-skimagedecoderfactory-returned-null  , но теперь получается, что изображение с камеры правильное, а когда сохраняет то повернутое... Наверное есть функция которая должна переворачивать картинку в правильное положение перед сохранением...